I have a shelf built onto paneling that I want to at least remove the bottom shelf
This shelf protrudes from the wall. The wall is paneled and you can see the panels through the shelf, so there is no actual back. It is about 4 feet up on the wall. I want to at least remove the bottom shelf.

Pictures will help.  If single shelves on the wall, there should be shelf brackets that are screwed to the wall.  A self standing shelving unit will be different.
